# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1), apt-get error:

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I have error in apt-get install it is a error:

```
>     > insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on
>     > system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting
>     > runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility
>     > `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends
>     > on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be
>     > true! insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and
>     > therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>     > Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system
>     > facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting runmbbservice
>     > depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>     > not be true! insserv: Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and
>     > therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv:
>     > Starting runmbbservice depends on plymouth and therefore on system
>     > facility `$all' which can not be true! insserv: Starting runmbbservice
>     > depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can
>     > not be true! insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached insserv: There
>     > is a loop at service runmbbservice if started insserv: There is a loop
>     > at service plymouth if started insserv:  loop involving service
>     > networking at depth 6 insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs
>     > at depth 3 insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
>     > insserv:  loop involving service runmbbservice at depth 1 insserv:
>     > exiting now without changing boot order! update-rc.d: error: insserv
>     > rejected the script header dpkg: error processing package
>     > unattended-upgrades (--configure):  subprocess installed
>     > post-installation script returned error exit status 1 No apport report
>     > written because MaxReports is reached already
>     >                                                               Errors were encountered while processing:  procps  udev  apache2 
> grub-common
>     > grub2-common  grub-pc-bin  grub-pc  lightdm  mysql-server-5.7  samba 
>     > whoopsie  grub2  bind9  gadmin-bind  proftpd-basic  gadmin-proftpd 
>     > gadmin-samba  gadmintools  mysql-server  php7.0-fpm 
>     > unattended-upgrades E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
>     > code (1)
```

I try several command like: apt-get -f install apt-get clean
I try change my source list, and remake apt-get update

Comment: Can you please paste that output as is, instead of with completely garbled formatting?

Comment: the full output message  www.dropbox.com/s/kprjlornkjcew35/dump.txt

Answer (score 0):

Based on dump.txt, it's apparent that you have a service script called `runmbbservice` which doesn't fit into the system properly, in a way that causes errors in any subsequent `insserv` call, e.g. the one initiated by the `procps` package.

If there is such a file in the `/etc/init.d/` directory, and it's not critical, can you try temporarily moving it away while you try to complete this operation?

Comment: i try that , but without result. i found this file /etc/rc2.d/S99runmbbservice, but without any output, may be tha cause the problem

Comment: @ASKRINASREDINNE that location is usually a symlink. What does `ls -l /etc/rc2.d/S99runmbbservice` tell you, where is it?